# Is there a wrapper for numpy / ndarrays that returns the array for each of the mutation methods?

Tags: python, numpy

The decision by `python` and apparently `numpy` to not return an object after its mutation is a source of frequent inconvenience.  This question will be based on a different approach: to use a `builder` pattern so that we can do this:

```
x = np.random.randint(0,10+1,50).sort()[:5]
```

and end up with the least five values from a random set of ten numbers. Instead the above results in a runtime error due to subscripting `None` after the `sort`.  I am wondering if there were either a library that provides that `builder` pattern atop `numpy`  or some way to coerce *all* mutation `numpy` methods to return `self` instead of `None`.

For a single mutation the `numpy` method might suffice:

```
x = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,10+1,50))[:5]
```

But that approach does not `scale` when a series of methods are required. E.g.

```
x = np.resize(np.sort(np.random.randint(0,10+1,50))[:5],[5,1])
```

That quickly becomes difficult not only to write but also to *read*: we are asked to both write and read the code "inside out" from right to left.

**Update** A "winner" was declared below. Making a slight modification - renaming from `ChainWrapper` to `Wrp` just for brevity - here is the usage on both a `list` and an (`numpy`)  `ndarray`:

```
Wrp(list(range(0,10,2))).append(8).append(10).insert(0, "hello").reverse().unwrap()[0:2]
# list:[10, 8]
import numpy as np
Wrp(np.linspace(0, 9, 10)).reshape(5, 2)[1:3, 0])
#  np.array: array([2., 4.])
```

The point is :  `append`, `insert` `reverse` and `reshape`  return None .  The `Wrp`  detects that and returns `self` instead.   Frequently I want to write a lambda that performs more than one operation on a list. It was not possible to do so without the above.

Comment: So instead of doing something like x=np.sort(np.random.randint(0,10+1,50))[:5], you want to be able to do it in the way you describe so you can string many methods using the builder pattern?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not returning a mutated object is a Pythonism that reminds you of the fact that no new object was created. Practically all standard library functions that do internal mutation return `None` for this reason.

You could write a wrapper of your own (and with some `getattr` magic, make it automatic), but it's probably not quite worth it.

*EDIT:* If you need this just for chaining, you could do something like

```
def chain(a, f):
    f(a)
    return a

x = chain(
    np.random.randint(0,10+1,50),
    lambda m: m.sort(),
)[:5]
```

or even fancier,

```
def hyperchain(val, *fs):
    for f in fs:
        res = f(val)
        if res is not None:
            val = res
    return val
```

to let you chain value-returning things and None-returning things:

```
x = hyperchain(
    np.random.randint(0,10+1,50),
    lambda m: m.sort(),
    lambda m: m[:5],
)
```

*EDIT 2:* Here's the aforementioned `getattr` wrapper idea -- not saying this is a good idea, or perfect, but here we go:

```
from functools import wraps


class ChainWrapper:
    def __init__(self, target):
        self._target = target

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        attr = getattr(self._target, key)
        if callable(attr):

            @wraps(attr)
            def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
                retval = attr(*args, **kwargs)
                if retval is None:
                    retval = self
                return retval

            return wrapped_func
        return attr

    def __str__(self):
        return self._target.__str__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<chain-wrapped {self._target!r}"

    def unwrap(self):
        return self._target

    # TODO: implement other things such as __getitem__ and __setitem__
    #       to just proxy through


l = [1, 2, 4, 8]

lw = ChainWrapper(l)
print(lw.append(8).append(10).insert(0, "hello").reverse())
```

This outputs

```
[10, 8, 8, 4, 2, 1, 'hello']
```

Comment: I am aware of this being a design decision in `python`.  I can not go back in time and debate on that at the time that decision were made: it's something I get to deal with (frequently..) . It leads to not being able to use the mutating methods in  expressions either  .   I would be fine to go and wrap the entire `numpy`  : but that will not work either since third party libraries will return unwrapped versions of `ndarrays`.

Comment: Thanks:  the `chaining` approach is something I do use: e.g. I have contributed to `pipe` https://julienpalard.github.io/Pipe/  and forked/enhanced  the `scalaps` as `infixpy`  https://github.com/javadba/infixpy . But explicitly saying `lambda` time and again is unwieldy.   It gets tiring for a functional leaning programmer to use this language but I'm trying..

Comment: You alluded to `__getattr__` : I am actually more interested in _that_ presently. Would you mind to explore that further?

Comment: That will still have the problem of you needing to re-wrap any numpy array you get from another library, so it'd be unwieldy. But see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091833/proxy-object-in-python

Comment: > unwieldy . Yes agreed the __getattr__ approach is limited in usefulness.  I am writing an entire library that extends `ndarray` so at least within _that_ library I can use this approach

Comment: Welp, added that idea too :)

Comment: wow that's great!  I _really_ don't care if this were considered _pythonic_ or not. I am just trying to find ways to _tolerate_ the language while being able to use the v good _numpy_ library and its friends.  This is one small step that direction.  In addition to the _collections chaining_ libraries mentioned earlier there are  some nice enhancements up my sleeve for usability of `ndarray`s

Comment: Glad I could help. As an aside, you may wish to add something to check if `retval` is _not_ `None`, it may need to be re-wrapped in a new ChainWrapper...

Comment: I am running into issues with the _not_ `None` case: how should the following be fixed to "re-wrap":  `return retval`

Comment: Maybe `if type(retval) == type(self._target): return ChainWrapper(retval)` or similar! Or you can always return a `ChainWrapper(retval)`...

Comment: fyi for `ndarray` this approach covers only a fraction of the bases:  in particular methods associated with `views` such as `clip`, `resize`, `reshape` and `slicing are different animals . But v instructive!  And it _is_ quite useful for builtin's like `list`, `dict`