# How to change __repr__ for an imported class of immutable type

Tags: python, gmp, gmpy

I am using `gmpy2` to work with high-precision floats (>500 bit of precision). My code contains long lists of such floats, e.g.

```python
import gmpy2

gmpy2.get_context().precision = 500
rs = gmpy2.random_state()
lst = [gmpy2.mpfr_random(rs) for _ in range(4)]
print(lst)

# [mpfr('0.271521109675768030046267124634073667684105281814578550174956682310741033886748
#  70742194330013240808110139077875599032334632394117927746462940740105086152',500), mpfr('0.651
#  70987608257463499855942595039172347625432569368637954337608487459435530015416379355871
#  784576133166076679114013337947978739119046252118327755675301311',500), mpfr('0.250491752647
#  45810463315271935029178260478893809777157454094624870772157985848539893902700198
#  946816912841670920043748676653996297679708199369887486126487',500), mpfr('0.35225 ...
```

As you see in this example, output tends to be unreadable because `mpfr.__repr__` prints all digits to the screen. I know in this example I could simply format the output

```python
print([f'{l}' for l in lst])
# ['0.271521', '0.651710', '0.250492', '0.352256']
```

However, I also have classes that internally contain `mpfr`s, and it'd be convenient that the automatically generated representations look more compact, for instance with only 10 digits.

I tried overwriting the `__repr__` method, but the naive attempt fails:

```python
BigFloat = gmpy2.mpfr
BigFloat.__repr__ = lambda self: 'bigfloat'

# TypeError: cannot set '__repr__' attribute of immutable type 'mpfr'
```

I also tried creating a new class that inherits from mpfr, but that also does not work

```python
class BigFloat(gmpy2.mpfr):

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'bigfloat'

# TypeError: type 'mpfr' is not an acceptable base type
```

I know I could create a new class `BigFloat` that internally contains a `gmpy2.mpfr`. Then I would reimplement all magic methods like `__add__`, `__neg__`, ... based on the `mpfr` class. But is there a more concise/elegant solution?

Comment: Using `__getattr__` would be more concise at least.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091833/proxy-object-in-python) about a proxy object help at all? You could have a proxy which forwarded all methods except `__repr__()`.

Comment: Btw if your goal is a readable print of the numbers, you would usually overwrite `__str__`, not `__repr__`. The latter is meant to produce a string representation that is as exact as possible, so it makes sense to print all digits there.